# show that there exist an element $g$ of a group $G$ such that $g^q$ is in $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

$H$ is normal in $G$ and $q$ is prime with $q\mid[G:H]$. Show that there exist $g$ in $G$ such that $g^{q}$ is in $H$.

I am not sure how to use $q\mid[G:H]$. Should I try to show that $f:G→H$, with $f(g)=g^q$ or there is better way to do it?

g can't be the identity

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it stands, the result is trivial - just pick any $g\in H$, or even $g=1$. 
I assume you want $g$ to be an element of $G$ that is *not* in $H$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen  I forgot to mention thatg can't be the identity. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, if we allow $g$ to be in $H$ the problem is trivial.  Here is how to find an element $g\notin H$ such that $g^q\in H$:

Look at the quotient group $G/H$.  This group has order divisible by $q$.  By Cauchy's theorem there is an element of $G/H$ of order $q$.  Hence it's representative $g$ satisfies $g^q\in H$, while $g\notin H$.

Also notice that the map you suggested defining in your question, $f(g)=g^q$, has image lying in $H$ iff every element $g\in G$ satisfies $g^q\in H$.  This will of course not be true in general since the quotient may have elements of order not dividing $q$.  For example, if some other prime $p$ divides $[G:H]$, the quotient will have an element of order $p$, again by Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Since $\vert G \vert = \vert H \vert \cdot [G:H]$ then doesn't $q$ divide $\vert G \vert$ and you could apply Cauchy's theorem in $G$ instead?

Comment: Good point, I guess this problem is kind of silly as stated.  Maybe the problem should be show there exists $g\in G$ such that $g^q\in H$ but no smaller positive powers of $g$ are in $H$?

Comment: In fact, if $g\notin H$ but $g^q\in H$ then $g$ must have order $q$ in the quotient group ($q$ is prime).  Thus the requirement $g\notin H$ (which was suggested above by Hagen von Eitzen) is equivalent to the one I suggested above.

Comment: Thinking now I think your approach is better because it is obvious that the element chosen isn't in $H$ where as my idea makes no such guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete, if we take the identy of $G$, it is obvius that for any $n$ $1^n=1$ is in $G$, but since $H$ is subgroup of $G$ then $1\in H$ so for any $n$ in particular for $q$ we have $1\in G$ and $1^q\in H$

Comment: I forgot to mention that g can't be the identity. My bad.

Comment: It must be diferent of the identy and diferente to another element of $H$ because $H$ is closed under multiplication(group operation), so that is why the solution given above works.

Answer (score 1):

With the hyphotesis, I will show that exist an element $g \in G$, and $g\not \in H$ such that $g^q\in H$. So We can take the group $G/H$ and since $q|[G:H]$ then $q$ divide the order of the group $G/H$, so by Couchy exist and elemente $g+H\in G/H$ with order $q$(since q is prime) therefore $g\not\in H$ because if that is true we will have that the order of $g+H$ will be 1, and it is $q$. So now we will se that $g^q\in H$, remenber $(g+H)^q=H$(H is the identy of $G/H)$, then $(g+H)^q=g^q+H=H$ in other words $g^q\in H$. So we conclude.

Comment: I hate to be rude, but I hope it wasn't you who downvoted my answer 6 minutes ago.  I noticed you were active 7 minutes ago.